# Why does my CSS background color repeat rather than cover?

Tags: html, css

The CSS I have written is below. I'm not sure why the background color repeats instead of covering. Thank you in advance for your help :)

```
body {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    color-stop(41%,rgba(41,137,216,1)), color-stop(77%,rgba(125,185,232,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Georgia,Arial,Serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

figure {
    float: left;
}

.question {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.answer {
    color: green;
    font-size: 16px;
}

#taskpic {
    float: right;
}

#audience {
    float: left;
    width: 550px;
    font-size: 16.5px;
}

#back {
    font-size: 15px;
}

#main {
    float: left;
    color: black;
    width: 160px;
    border: 1px solid brown;
    border-style: double;
    padding: 2px;
    font-size: 18.5px;
}

#youarehere {
    color: black;
}

#name {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding-left: 515px;
}

figure figcaption {
    text-align: center;
}

ul {
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid  blue;
    width: 200px;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

li a:link {
    color: red;
}

li a:visited {
    color: red;
}

li a:focus {
    color: red;
}

li a:hover {
    color: blue;
}

li a:active {
    color: blue;
}

a:link {
    color: black;
}

a:visited {
    color: black;
}

a:focus {
    color: black;
}

a:hover {
    color: red;
}

a:active {
    color: red;
}

h2 a:link {
    color: pink;
}

h2 a:visited {
    color: pink;
}

h2 a:focus {
    color: pink;
}

h2 a:hover {
    color: red;
}

h2 a:active {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: For which specific element of your html it repeats?

Comment: A http://www.jsfiddle.net/ or a picture regarding the output?

Comment: This is a duplicate of the poster’s question a few hours ago.

Comment: Please do not post the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

`color-stop` is not a valid CSS property.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

You need to use something like this:

```
body {
    background: #ff0000;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(41,137,216,1) 41%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 77%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(41%,rgba(41,137,216,1)), color-stop(77%,rgba(125,185,232,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(41,137,216,1) 41%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 77%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(41,137,216,1) 41%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 77%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(41,137,216,1) 41%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 77%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(41,137,216,1) 41%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 77%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff0000', endColorstr='#00ff00',GradientType=0 );
}
```

This is a good tool for generating cross-browser background gradients: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Also, `background-size` is for background images.

Answer (score 0):

This code should and could set your background to cover:

```
    background-size:cover;
```

Try using the "full background" set of code:

```
    body {
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    background-size:cover;
    }
```

Hope this helped.